# How to add custom piclist field to send email page layout?

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, activities, send-email

I have a requirement where I have to add a custom picklist filed on send email page layout. I know it is not possible through standard Salesforce function. Kindly let me know if you are aware of any workaround or other approach.

Please help!

Russell

Comment: I would suggest you to create a custom send email page and add your any custom objects there. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: the custom picklist field - what role does it play?  You can't solve this without a vf solution that starts to get complex if you want user to be able to choose different templates and add attachments